# Screen get abnormal when I rotate screen using java on Android TV api 29

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tv, screen-rotation

I am rotating the screen from landscape to portrait but the screen works abnormally when I do this. The screen size gets small.

The app is working fine in android API version 23 but with 29 this issue is occurring.

here is my code:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
```

Before Rotation
[image]

After Rotation
[image]

Here is my XML file I am using this app on android tv

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:banner="@mipmap/ic_banner"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".ServerActivity"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".yourActivityRunOnStartup"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".yourActivityRunOnStartup"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".InternetActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DownloadActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayActivity"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <!--            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"-->

    <activity
        android:name=".PinActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:exported="false"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Comment: Share your XML layout and other source code. Why are you using an Android TV emulator? Android TV always displays in landscape mode.

Comment: I have designed app for tv in which I need rotation to portrait mode

Comment: I suggest you read the developer training page on building [Android TV layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts). It clearly states that Android TV always displays in landscape mode.

Comment: is there any way to rotate it to potrait?

Comment: Google play console will be reject the app due to the portrait mode added in the any of the screen in the tv application

Comment: any one got this answer? please help me, stuck in this for above a week.

Comment: I got the answer Instead of rotating the screen rotate the layout this solve the issue